# Vue - How to make <b-tab> active dynamically based on external control

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, v-model

How do I make a tab active dynamically based on which button is pressed. I'm using the `<b-tabs>` from `bootstrap-vue`. From my example code below the `step` variable is changed according to the button pressed, but the tabs are always active regardless.

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <b-tabs>
                <b-tab title="Step 1" :active="step === 1">
                   <br>step 1
                </b-tab>
                <b-tab title="Step 2" :active="step === 2">
                    <br>step 2
                </b-tab>
                <b-tab title="Step 3" :active="step === 3">
                    <br>step 3
                </b-tab>
            </b-tabs>

            <button v-on:click="step = 1">Step 1</button>
            <button v-on:click="step = 2">Step 2</button>
            <button v-on:click="step = 3">Step 3</button>

        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    step: 0,
                }
            },
            mounted() {
            },
            methods: {
            },
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `v-model` as mentioned [`in this example`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/#external-controls) instead of `active` prop as follows :

```
        <b-tabs v-model="step">
            <b-tab title="Step 1" >
               <br>step 1
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Step 2" >
                <br>step 2
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Step 3" >
                <br>step 3
            </b-tab>
        </b-tabs>
```

and your step should begin from `0`

```
        <button v-on:click="step = 0">Step 1</button>
        <button v-on:click="step = 1">Step 2</button>
        <button v-on:click="step = 2">Step 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanls, this solved the main issue. What I'm actually trying to do is to only have one tab active at a time, all other should be disabled. User should not be able to click on disabled tab. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: try something like `<b-tab title="Step 1" :disabled="step !== 0">`

Comment: I had to remove v-model="step" for that to work, but once again it pointed me to the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is another way that you can use.

```
<b-tabs>
    <b-tab :active="selected_tab_name === 'first_tab'"></b-tab>
    <b-tab :active="selected_tab_name === 'second_tab'"></b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

and set the `selcted_tab_name` like this:

`<b-button @click="selected_tab_name = 'first_tab'">Activate first tab</b-button>`

I think this way is more readable.